# How to check permission rules in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce

I'm using drupal commerce and I added a new product (and product display).
I can see it in the listing, but when a user click on the product page, it's saying : permission denied.
All the other products works fine, it's only the last one which doesn't.

I tried to rebuild the permissions but that doesn't changed anything. How can I check what is "denying" the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that for drupal 7, the `devel` module as a submodule called `developper node access` which shows exactly what I want. For this you need first to enable it and the active the `access by user block`. This block shows for every users if the current node is accessible and if not why (i.e. which module is denying it).

Answer (score 1):

The [Access denied backtrace](https://www.drupal.org/project/adb) module should help you

Answer (score 0):

If your using Apache you might as well look at your .htaccess configurations. I faced a similar issue in the past and by using appropriate permission in the .htaccess file everything fell in place.

Refer http://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file to learn more about configuring .htaccess file